# Como ler um arquivo de texto e pegar os valores como inteiros?

Tags: c++

Quero saber como realizar a leitura de um arquivo em c++. A primeira linha tem o tamanho da matriz e na demais tem os elementos da matriz. Cada elemento está separado por um espaço em branco, podendo haver números negativos. As linhas terminam com `\n`.

Fiz isso mas não tem dado muito certo.

```
int main() {

    FILE *file = NULL;
    int *array = NULL;
    int matrixSize = 0;
    int arraySize = 0;
    char linha[255];

    fopen_s(&file, "matriz.txt", "rt");
    rewind(file);
    fscanf_s(file, "%d", &matrixSize);
    printf("%d", matrixSize);

    arraySize = matrixSize * matrixSize;

    alocateArray(&array, arraySize);
    cleanArray(array, arraySize);

    int i = 0;

    while(!feof(file)) {

        fgets(linha, 255, file);
        char *valores = strtok(linha, " ");

        while(valores != NULL) {
            //array[i++] = (int) valores;
            printf("%s", valores);
        }
    }

    fclose(file);

    system("PAUSE");

}
```

Comment: Se você for usar isso para trabalhar e não para estudar, aprenda a mexer com banco de dados (MS Windows: SQL, Cross-Platform: MySQL (Oracle).http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ktheed7h(v=vs.90).aspx (opção de tradução emcima) e  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connector-cpp-info.html

Comment: @LucasHenrique apenas para fins de estudo

Comment: @LucasHenrique Não vejo como BDs seriam uma boa alternativa para um problema que envolva manipulação de  matrizes.

Comment: @C.E.Gesser não quero dizer maninpulação de matrizes, e sim busca de dados. Costuma ser feita em binário... Aprender a mexer com banco de dados é muito importante :)

Comment: Certamente é importante, assim como é importante saber a melhor ferramenta para cada problema. Pela descrição provavelmente depois de ler a matriz vai ser necessário algum tipo de manipulação, e para isso  é bom ter tudo em memória mesmo.

Comment: @C.E.Gesser, vou ter que paralelizar o método de jacobi calculando a matriz inserida

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>

int main() {
  std::ifstream file("matriz.txt");
  unsigned size;
  file >> size; 

  if (!file) {
    //erro durante leitura
  }

  std::vector<int> matrix;
  matrix.reserve(size*size);

  while (true) {
    double value;
    if (!(file >> value)) {
      break;
    }
    matrix.push_back(value);
  }

  if (matrix.size() != size*size) {
    //erro durante leitura
  }
  //usa matriz
}
```

Comment: Por que `file >> size`?

Comment: Porque a primeira coisa que há no arquivo é o tamanho da matriz, pelo menos é o que está no enunciado.

Comment: Legal :) Obrigado.

Comment: @C.E.Gesser, não esta pegando o valor da primeira linha, ao debugar demonstra erro, estou usando visual studio

Comment: O arquivo `matriz.txt` está na pasta de onde você está rodando o executável?

Comment: Estou usando o visual studio, pelo fopen não estava, estava em local diferente do executável, pois o mesmo o criou em um dir diferente. Vou colocar o txt no mesmo nível do executável.

Comment: Esse provavelmente já era seu erro no início

Comment: Não é problema do arquivo estar no mesmo nível do executável, coloquei, mas com o código antigo a leitura era feita.

Comment: Eu fiz um teste aqui com uma pequena matriz 2x2 e funcionou. Mas acabei encontrando um problema no meu código que fazia ele ler um elemento a mais, já corrigi. Se o problema continuar, acho que vamos precisar que você mostre um exemplo do arquivo de matriz, só por garantia.

Comment: ok, mas é um arquivo que a primeira linha tem um numero e quebra de linha, segunda linhas numeros separados por espaço em branco.

Comment: Achei a resposta neste [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6323619/c-ifstream-error-using-string-as-opening-file-path), agora preciso trabalhar para pegar as demais linhas.

Comment: @C.E.Gesser Desse jeito é muito mais rápido a leitura de arquivo...

Comment: Bom que deu certo, boa sorte no resto do problema agora!

Answer (score 3):

Se tratando de C++ você pode usar a [`std::fstream`](http://pt.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_fstream) e os [operadores de leitura da `std::istream`](http://pt.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt). Um exemplo:

```
#include <fstream>

int main() {
    std::ifstream file("matriz.txt");
    if (!file) {/* Falhou em abrir o arquivo */}

    int size;
    if (!(file >> size)) {/* Falhou em ler o primeiro valor */}

    int* matriz = new int[size * size];
    for (int i = 0; i < size*size; ++i) {
        if (!(file >> matriz[i])) {/* Falhou em ler um dos valores */}
    }

    // Faça algo com sua matriz aqui.

    delete[] matriz;
}
```

Uma característica útil é que o `operator>>` retorna a própria stream (o arquivo), e testar a stream como um valor booleano (`if (!file)`) retorna se ocorreu um erro na última leitura ou escrita. Dai o idioma `if (!(file >> var)) {/*erro*/}`.

Comment: o operador `>>` é de binário?

Comment: Não. Ele lê valores formatados, como `56` ou `-874`.

Comment: O operador `>>` tem duas funcionalidades no C++: bitwise shift right e "get-from" stream. Da mesma forma, existe o operador `<<` que faz as operações opostas. Em C++ esses operadores foram sobrecarregados (sim, em C++ operadores também podem ser sobrecarregados) para ter essas funcionalidades especificas em streams.